# Matlab: Creating a while loop which stops a Taylor Series approximation after it reaches a specified error?

Tags: matlab

Say I take the taylor series of e^x, for n terms, centered at a=0 for some random value until the error reaches a specified value.

The error is `error=(exp(x)-approx)/(exp(x))` and the specified value the error should reach is `err=0.01`

I have managed to generate a taylor series

```
x=2;
j=1;
for s=[0:1:10]
approx=approx+(x^s)/(factorial(s))
end
```

However, I am unable to integrate a while loop which extends the series until the statement `error>err` is false.

I tried

```
x=2;
j=1;
err=0.01

error=(exp(x)-approx)/(exp(x));
while error>err
for s=[0:1:10]
approx=approx+(x^s)/(factorial(s))
end
end
```

and

```
x=2;
j=1;
err=0.01;
s=-1

error=(exp(x)-approx)/(exp(x));
while error>err
s=s+1
approx=approx+(x^s)/(factorial(s))
end
```

None of them give the correct answer.

How can I solve the problem.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I dont get anything. The terms never end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your error calculation is within the `for` loop and initialize the terms:

```
x=2;
j=1;
err=0.01;
s=0;
error = 1e10;
approx = 0;
while error>err
    approx=approx+(x^s)/(factorial(s));
    error=(exp(x)-approx)/(exp(x));
    s=s+1
end
```

Comment: You can initialize it with anything larger than `err` - I just chose a ridiculously high value.